# base64 decoding works differently in node than in php, perl or python

Tags: php, python, node.js, base64, decoding

I need to decode a base64 token for an authentication string, and I found some working examples in Python, Perl and PHP, and I wrote the equivalent code in Node, but I ran into an issue. It seems the base64 decoder for Node doesn't work the same way as for the other 3 languages.

Running this in Python

```
token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe'
decoded_token = token.decode('base64')
print decoded_token
```

returns this string

> ???F#`?D^

Running this in Perl

```
my $token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe';
my $decoded_token = decode_base64($token);
print $decoded_token;
```

returns this string

> ???F#`?D^

Running this in PHP

```
$token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe';
$decoded_token = base64_decode($token, true);
echo $decoded_token;
```

returns this string

> ???F#`?D^

and finally, running this in a Node script

```
var token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe',
decoded_token = Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString();
console.log(decoded_token);
```

returns this string

> ????F#`?D^

The question is, why the extra question mark in the decoded string? And how can I get the same result in Node as I get in Perl, Python and PHP?

**UPDATE**

running this in the command line

```
echo BaSe64sTRiNghERe | base64 --decode
```

gives me the same output as the perl, python and php scripts

but running the same command from node

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('echo BaSe64sTRiNghERe | base64 --decode', function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

I still get the wrong stuff.

Comment: did you try on real token - ie. `QmFTZTY0c1RSaU5naEVSZQ==` - after decoding it gives `BaSe64sTRiNghERe`

Answer (score -1):

The output is different since you have generated unprintable characters, and node seems to handle those unprintable characters differently from the other languages. You are also losing information:

```
>>> token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe'
>>> decoded_token = token.decode('base64')
>>> print decoded_token
???F#`?D^
>>> decoded_token[0] == decoded_token[1]
False
```

If you modify your python snippet to look like this:

```
import binascii
token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe'
decoded_token = binascii.hexlify(token.decode('base64'))
print(decoded_token)
```

Then modify your nodejs snippet to look like this:

```
var token = 'BaSe64sTRiNghERe',
decoded_token = Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString('hex');
console.log(decoded_token);
```

You will avoid the differences in how they handle unprintable characters and see that the base64 decodes have the same byte values.

Comment: Further on, I need to do this
`key = decoded_token[:5]

text = 'concatenated data here'

digest = hmac.new(key, text, hashlib.sha1).digest()

print digest.encode('hex')`

the equivalent in node being
`key = decoded_token.substr(0, 5);
text = 'concatenated data here';
digest = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(text).digest('hex');
console.log('digest', digest)`

And they output different hex values. (if I use the same key to create the hmac, the hex values are the same)